# Norm in $\mathcal{C}[\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R}]$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I’m interested in expliciting a norm in the space of continuous functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to itself. It does not need to induce a complete metric.

Comment: "Expliciting?" What is your question?

Comment: I know you can show the existence of such a norm by means of the Axiom of Choice. However this approach is naturally not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity implies Riemann integrability. Multiplication preserves continuity, so the product is Riemann integrable. For $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$, we can define the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle: V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$ \langle f, g \rangle  = \int_a^b fg $$
This induces a norm via $\langle f, f\rangle = \| f \|^2$.

EDIT: Only a semi-norm. Not an inner product space. Semi-norm is given by
$$ \| f \| = \sqrt{\int_a^b f^2} $$
I believe you can quotient out by the kernal of the semi-norm to create a norm but this may be incorrect and probably violates the conditions of the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a norm in ${\cal C}(\mathbb{R})$, it defines a seminorm.

Comment: That makes it only a seminorm ($||f||=0 \not\Rightarrow f=0$).

Comment: I can only see counterexamples for $b\leq a$. I should have said $a<b$. In this case, are there still counter examples?

Comment: A function that is 0 on an interval, and has a non zero value somewhere else. Think of bump functions.

Comment: Ah right definitely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, as others have mentionned, this doesn’t define a norm. For any $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$, you can easily find a non-zero continuous function that equals $0$ in the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: Yes, there are. For any $a<b$, take $f(x)=0$ for $x\in(a,b)$ and $f(x)=|x-\frac{a+b}{2}|-\frac{b-a}{2}$ for $x\notin(a,b)$, for example.